# How to set normal Chinese font in MS Power Point 2016?

Tags: fonts

In `Ecxel` I can set `Calibri` font and enter Chinese characters, which look straight. In `PowerPoint` I have Chinese characters set font as `STXinwei (Body)` and they look very "stylish":

[image]

I can't get "straight" font in PowerPoint and can't change font to `Calibri` (it turns back to `STXinwei (Body)`.

How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calibri does not contain Chinese characters. When you set your font to Calibri, Microsoft Office automatically choose a Chinese font for Chinese you’ve entered.

In your case, it seems that Excel automatically chose Microsoft Yahei (微软雅黑), while Powerpoint automatically chose STXinwei (华文新魏).

They are both correct behaviors. In Excel, people expect to see more general fonts in sheets, while, in PowerPoint, people expect to see more stylish fonts in presentations.

Though what PowerPoint did is correct, if you do want to change the font in PowerPoint, you have to keep in mind that **Calibri does not contain Chinese characters**. Therefore, you have to **choose another Chinese font** for it so that the appearance would change.

I personally recommend Microsoft Yahei (the font Excel uses) and STZhongsong (a very bold serif font suitable for presentation titles).

Answer (score 1):

Try **黑体**

Here's my power point and your pic:

[image: yup]

I would say it looks like the same font.

Or set it to **宋体**.

Here's my PP next to your excel picture.

[image: yeah]

It's not a perfect match but it's a surefire way to give you the look you want.